# How to view any website in a native way on OSX?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, browser

Mac OS X: 10.9.5

### The problem:

I often have 20+ browser tabs open from various web apps. Combined with running a comparable number of native apps, I need a better way to avoid cycling through two different places to find whatever I need at any given time.

Essentially I want to have the best of both worlds and find a way to combine web apps with native apps so I can see them all when I `Cmd-Tab`.

### `Cmd-Tab` has these advantages:

1. It's essentially one step.
2. The app you want has an easily
   recognizable icon.
3. I can hit `Cmd-Tab` and hold `Cmd` to view all
   the apps by icon.

### `Cmd-Backtick` limitations:

I realize I could make separate browser windows and use `Cmd-Backtick`, but:

1. Making separate browser windows is an extra required step.
2. You have already be in the app whose windows you want to cycle through or add an extra step to get to the app.
3. There is no pre-visual when cycling through windows of the same app as you arrive at the next window without warning.
4. It's easy to lose your place when cycling if you can't remember how many windows are open or whatever order they were in.

### `Ctrl-Down` limitations

`Ctrl-Down` could be used to cycle through an app's windows, however:

1. Like `Cmd-Backtick`, you have already be in the app whose windows you want to cycle through or add an extra step to get to the app.
2. Also like `Cmd-Backtick`, making separate browser windows is an extra required step.
3. While viewing the window's content might be advantageous in some situations, a browser's content often changes and so immediately recognizing the window that you want is not as instant as an icon that you see all the time.

### Why not use the browser's cycle features?

1. Using `Ctrl-Tab` or `Cmd-Shift-}` to linearly cycle through browser tabs is quite tiring with 20+ browser windows.
2. Selecting browser tabs with the mouse also becomes ineffective at 20+ browser tabs as the title only has ~4 characters that identify the tab.
3. Browser icons alone just sort of get you in the right neighbordhood and then it's `Ctrl-Tab` or `Cmd-Shift-}` time all over again.

### What about web clips?

I'm looking for something like a web clip on iOS. Web clips are websites that are essentially bookmarks with icons on your dash. One drawback to web clips, however, is that they open in Safari so when double tapping home to cycle through apps (similar to `Cmd-Tab` in OSX), you get a Safari icon and not the web clip icon.

### No custom browsers

I don't want a mac app that is a custom browser because of their unpredictability.

### Summary

I want to run a browser of my choosing as a separate app that at least initially points to a particular website. I'd like to give it a different name and icon, repeating this as many times as desired. I could settle for not giving the app a new name, but not having the icon is a deal breaker. I would totally cut my own graphics for the icons if I had to.

Comment: Build one or open each tab as a new window

Comment: @Tim how is your suggestion different from my Cmd-Backtick limitations section. Did I miss something?

Comment: What you're asking for does not exist.